# Button won't submit post request after adding remote: true in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building a nested form in my rails app, for resource `recipe` that has many `ingredients`.  I have included a link with `remote: true` on the form which adds additional `ingredients` fields controlled via jQuery/AJAX script.  However, now the button on my form won't submit the post request.

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
<h1>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
</h1>
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |p| %>
    <%= render 'ingredient_form', f: p %>
    <%= link_to "Add ingredient", recipe_new_path, id: "new_ingredient", remote: true %>
<% end %>
<h1>
    <%= f.label :steps %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :steps %><br>
</h1>
<%= f.submit "Add" %><br>
<% end %>

... _ingredient_form
<%= form_for :ingredients do |p| %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= p.label :ing %><br>
            <%= p.text_area :ing %><br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= p.label :amount %><br>
            <%= p.text_area :amount %><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Recipes controller:

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new  
  @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.build
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.create!(recipe_params)
  redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
end
```

new.js.erb:

```
$("#new_ingredient").before("<%= j render 'ingredient_form', f: p %>");
```

Link to GitHub repo:

https://github.com/jlcampbell1991/recipe-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was using `form_for` instead of `field_for` in my partial, the form was rendering the button OUTSIDE of the form element.